# isupper() does not pick up all of the uppercase words in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am doing a task for school in a beginner Python course that requires a function which removes all the words that are in capital letters using the string method isupper() and gives a new list as an output, which includes only the words that are not in all caps, for example:

**List given:**

```
my_list = ["ABC", "def", "UPPER", "ANOTHERUPPER", "lower", "another lower", "Capitalized"]
```

**Expected output:**

```
['def', 'lower', 'another lower', 'Capitalized']
```

This is what i currently have:

```
def no_shouting(my_list):
    for word in my_list:
        if word.isupper() == True:
            my_list.remove(word)
    return my_list
if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_list = ["ABC", "def", "UPPER", "ANOTHERUPPER", "lower", "another lower", "Capitalized"]
    pruned_list = no_shouting(my_list)
    print(pruned_list)
```

Even though everything is seemingly fine to my rookie eyes, here is what my code gives as an output:

```
['def', 'ANOTHERUPPER', 'lower', 'another lower', 'Capitalized']
```

So for some reason, it does not remove the word "ANOTHERUPPER", but it removes every other uppercase word. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange result when removing item from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it)

Comment: Oh, i see. I checked out the question @Holloway added but I still can't seem to wrap my mind around on how am I supposed to solve this issue, as we have not used e.g. `enumerate` yet in our classes so I doubt I'm allowed to use a technique like that on this.

Answer (score 0):

As Holloway said "you're modifying the list as you're iterating through it". You should avoid mutating collection. To achieve what you want, you are basically writing the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function. Instead of creating a new tool, why not use the right existing tool for the job? Here is how:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_list = ["ABC", "def", "UPPER", "ANOTHERUPPER", "lower", "another lower", "Capitalized"]
    pruned_list = list(filter(lambda word : not(word.isupper()), my_list))
    print(pruned_list)
```

or without the `lambda` keyword

```
def isNotUpper(word):
    return not(word.isupper())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_list = ["ABC", "def", "UPPER", "ANOTHERUPPER", "lower", "another lower", "Capitalized"]
    pruned_list = list(filter(isNotUpper, my_list))
    print(pruned_list)
```

output

```
['def', 'lower', 'another lower', 'Capitalized']
```

or more exactly you are doing a `filterfalse`:

```
import itertools 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_list = ["ABC", "def", "UPPER", "ANOTHERUPPER", "lower", "another lower", "Capitalized"]
    pruned_list = list(itertools.filterfalse(str.isupper, my_list))
    print(pruned_list)
```

[source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse)

Comment: Or `filterfalse(str.isupper, my_list)`

Comment: This seems to be working, but I am not "allowed" to use `lambda` etc. as we have not yet been taught those.

Comment: @ssaaradd a lambda is basically an anonymous function. A function without any name. The second example doesn't need the keyword `lambda`. I added an alternative version of the first example without lambda